# Unable to open Mobile SDK 2.3 project in Android Studio

Tags: mobilesdk, sfdcmobilesdk-android

My Android Studio does not recognize any of the sample apps with Force.com Android SDK as a valid project. What steps do I need to take to open and run it there?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is because Gradle support was actually introduced in Mobile SDK [3.0](https://github.com/forcedotcom/SalesforceMobileSDK-Android/tree/v3.0.0) which was released in January end. Please upgrade to 3.1 and you should be good to go.

The 3.0 release notes states

> Other Technical Improvements
>
> Various bug fixes.
>
> **Android Studio and the Gradle build system are now fully supported.**